# How to name and save the file using the contents of a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to name and save the file using the contents of a single cell OR multiple cells

I want to populate a cell with the contents of 3 other cells and then use that cell as the file name

example docket number + client + description

thx

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. This site is about helping resolve problems you actually have, not placing orders for someone to do things for you. To increase your chance of getting an answer, please [edit] your question to let us know what you have already researched and tried. Also include how the data is arranged in the worksheet.

Comment: Which part is the problem for you? Knowing how to save the file? Creating a name using the three cell? @CharlieRB is right to suggest you need to exhibit some effort. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Populating the cell is easy, assuming you have your "docket number" in cell A1, your "client" number or name in cell B1 and your "description" in cell C1 simply enter the forumla:
=A1&"-"&B1&"-"&C1
You can replace the "-" with whatever you want to be your seperator, just remember to include the "" around it.
Naming the document is much more difficult and I do not know of any solution to automatically change this option, there are many examples of VBA scripts that can name it to the contents of that specific cell, but you would need to run the macro every time you are to save the document.